# Java: Set the default button

Tags: java, netbeans

To set the default button to suppose `jButton4` the following code has to be used: `this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButton4);` But where to add this?

**What all I tried:**
I tried to add it in main function but it gave me an error, I tried to put it inside the button action performed block but it did not work, I tried to put it just before the main function it gave me an error.

**Question:** So where do I put this line of code so it works? I am using Netbeans GUI to make the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this line everywhere you want to set the default button (a button click, where you create your UI etc.).

I think a nice place is where you create your UI elements.

In your case it would be, just after `initComponents();`

Comment: I do not create my UI elements myself :P

Comment: So call it after the method which creates the UI for you.

Comment: Can this be done in anyway using the Netbeans IDE UI, I mean without programmatically.